# On-boarding dockerized model, model build for onap and license problem in acumos clio

Tags: acumos

I installed acumos 3.02 in Ubuntu 16.04 & 3.03 in Ubuntu 18.04 through system-integration successfully.
I can on-board model through "ON-BOARDING BY WEB", but I have some problem.

1.On-boarding dockerized model

I tried to on-board a docker image model, and according to https://docs.acumos.org/en/clio/submodules/on-boarding/docs/onboarding-pre_dockerised_and_URI_guide.html, after I type the name of the model, 
I should get

acumos_domain:docker_proxy_port/modelname_soultion_id:tag.

Howerver I got

acumos_domain:kube_proxy_port/modelname_soultion_id:tag,

so I couldn't push my model to acumos
Does anyone know how to fix it?

2.model build for onap

I want to convert my model to be used in ONAP, but "Build for ONAP button" never be displayed in my acumos.

I have on-boarded some simple models, like model from https://github.com/acumos/python-dcae-model-runner/tree/master/example
What I have to do to make models compatible with ONAP?

I found models in https://marketplace.acumos.org with "Build for ONAP" button can't be downloaded ,it will show "Page Not Found", is it normal?

3.license problem

When I try to download anythings from my marketplace, it will shows:
swid-tag(XXXX) not found & license-profile() not found for swid-tag(XXXX)

I found it will happen in https://marketplace.acumos.org too.
Does anyone can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to use the very last version of CLIO (3.0.29) https://wiki.acumos.org/display/REL/Acumos_Clio_Point_Release_Special_Patch

Regarding your second point, some answer here : https://jira.acumos.org/browse/ACUMOS-3999